# Случайное выполнение действия

Tags: php

К примеру, у меня есть два действия :

```
echo '1'; // 25% что выполниться, а второе действие нет.

echo '2'; // 75% что выполниться, а первое действие нет.
```

Как сделать, чтобы действия выполнялись случайно (в каком-то проценте допустим)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну например:

```
$random = rand(1, 100);
if($random <= 75) {
    echo 'я буду вызываться чаще';
    //это действие будет выполнятся в 75% случаев
}
else {
    echo 'а я реже :(';
    //соответственно это в 25%
}
```

В вашем случае имхо самое рациональное решение

Comment: Или просто: `if (rand(1, 4) == 4) echo '1';`

Comment: я просто для наглядности написал, нам же неисзвестно что ТС собирается делать внутри этих условий, вдруг у него там 100500строчная логика будет :D

Comment: возможно я ошибаюсь но 
    if($random >= 75) 

должно быть 

    if($random <= 75)

Comment: нет, не ошибаетесь, опечатался, <br><small>fixed</small>

Comment: Всё верно. Рандом от 1 до 100. То, что он меньше 75 - это шанс 3/4, а не 1/4. Вопрос только в том, насколько рандом равномерен вообще) наверно равномерен.

Comment: рандом нато и рандом, перед стартом всегда будет 1/4...<br>
Не хочу вас обидеть никак, а в чем собственно разница сначало исполняется 3/4, а потом 1/4 или наоборот?<br>Вы просто написали так какбудто бы это разные вещи...

Comment: вы б поаккуратнее с псевдослучайностями. На спектрумах число от напряжения в момент запроса на проце зависило...

Comment: эм...чаво? :DDD Вы наверно не в тот вопрос написали  :)

Answer (score 1):

То тогда используйте код

```
 $number =  mt_rand(1,2);
if ($number==1){
echo '1';
}
if ($number==2){
echo '2';
}
__________
```

`$number =  mt_rand(1,2);` - это значит, что мы загоняем в переменную `$number` случайное число от `1` до `2` и с помощью условий проверяем какое в ней значение, если `1` то выводим `1`, если `2` то тогда `2` и т.д. Если таких методов будет много то используй конструкцию `switch` и `case`

Comment: какойто ужас, условие 50 на 50 кагБы пишется просто if-else xDDD

Answer (score 0):

Если почитать внимательно курс теории вероятности, то вероятность приближается к своему значению при больших количествах повторений, т.е. вероятность 75% это не 3 из 4 и даже не 75 из 100, можно смело брать 7500000 из 10000000. Теперь почитав ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО описание функции rand() и немного оптимизировав код получаем:

```
echo (rand(0,10000000)>7500000)?2:1;
```

как-то так, **причем чем больше число тем ближе вероятность распределения**